# RailsTutorial Chapter 3 - I just cannot get my tests to pass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm working my way through the RailsTutorial book and have stalled in Chapter 3.
I'm beginning to feel like I'm going insane!

The autogenerated tests for the 'home' and 'contact' pages work fine, but try as I might I cannot get my test for the 'about' page to pass.
I have (and I tell no lie) created and the deleted the addional lines in the routes.rb file and the pages_controller.rb file and created the view file no fewer than 4 times just in case I had some strange non-printing characters.  I must have checked my versions against the sample code from the book at least twice that many times!

I temporarily changed the 'about' test case into a second 'contact' test just to prove that the syntax of the test case is fine.  It works OK.

To make matters worse, the 'about' page actually renders fine in the browser...
I've just created another new page called 'landing' and I get the same failure.

It's like the autogenerated tests were sprinkled with fairy dust!

Has anybody experienced similar?
I guessing that it's something glaringly obvious, but after 5 hours with no visible progress frustration has got the better of me...

I'm using Ubuntu 10.04, Ruby 1.9.2, Rails 3.0.3

***RESOLVED***  An Issue with spork not reloading files

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you've been thorough. So this isn't working?

```
# pages_controller_spec.rb
describe "GET 'landing'" do
    it "should be successful" do
        get 'landing'
        response.should be_success
    end
end

# pages_controller.rb
def landing
end

# routes.rb
get "pages/landing"

# views/pages/landing.html.erb
blah
```

Comment: When I wrote the post neither 'about' nor 'landing' worked and they looked like your model.No... However I took a break and had a thought.

Comment: Yes as you indicated.  GOT IT!!  It's a spork problem.  I had to restart spork because I created a new project and autogenerated the pages so I could use diff on the file pairs.  When I restarted spork for my original project it worked!  I had a squizz and it is mentioned in the RailsTutorial book - A prefork issue  (Beyond my knowledge at the moment), but at least I'll know what to do if it happeneds again.  Thanks.